# French (online) dictionary equivalent to dictionary.cambridge.org/ (classification of words according to their level: A1, A2, etc.)

Tags: dictionnaires, niveau-de-langue, internet

One of the things that I greatly enjoy to the online Cambridge dictionary is the classification of the words and idioms according to Common European Framework of Reference for Languages. So for instance

> [out of the blue](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/out-of-the-blue)   C1
>
> If something happens out of the blue, it is
> completely unexpected: One day, out of the blue, she announced that
> she was leaving.

and

> [nevertheless](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nevertheless)
> (also nonetheless)   B2
>
> despite what has just been said
> or referred to

and so on. Is there a similar (free) online dictionary that does the same for the French language?

Comment: https://www.cnrtl.fr/portail/ Click on the term Exemple, to get to the dictionary quickly. Centre nationale de ressources textuelles et lexicales It's more like the OED, the big one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what I want but still quite helpful: https://www.bonjourdefrance.co.uk/learn-french-online/vocabulary/exercices-intermediate#

I think there is not a site like online Cambridge dictionary for the French language.

https://www.cnrtl.fr/portail/ comes close but does not provide such a classification. And its vocabulary has not been updated since the 90s (if I remember correctly).